How to get a list of timezones in Postgresql with full timezone name?
I found a list of timezones in the Postgresql docs for an older version https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/timezones.html
I want that same list but for the current version. I ran the following code but it doesn't return a similar list:
SELECT *
FROM pg_timezone_names;

Instead that returns region/city name instad of the full name of the timezone/standard time e.g:
Europe/London       BST
Europe/Luxembourg   CEST
Europe/Madrid       CEST
Europe/Malta        CEST

Is there a way to get a list like in the link?:
EDT     -04:00  Eastern Daylight Time
CDT     -05:00  Central Daylight Time
EST     -05:00  Eastern Standard Time
CST     -06:00  Central Standard Time


You won't get a description - but isn't Europe/Vienna descriptive enough? PostgreSQL just uses the IANA time zone database, so it is not PostgreSQL's task to document it. Will a list like this one help?

@LaurenzAlbe Europe/Vienna is a region but not a timezone. The timezone would be Central European Savings Time. I suppose I would have to make a new table with a mapping of everything which I thought might already be done somewhere.

No it is a timezone also, see Timezone list. Also from here Europe/Vienna: In the IANA time zone database, Austria is given the zone Europe/Vienna.

Just for fun - tryed to get the zones in more organized form out of (quite messy) pg_timezone_names table. Try it like here (v.16):
WITH
  grid AS
    ( Select  Case When Position('/' In Replace(name, 'posix/', '')) > 0
                   Then SubStr(Replace(name, 'posix/', ''), 1, Position('/' In Replace(name, 'posix/', '')) - 1)
              Else Replace(name, 'posix/', '')
              End as region,
              Case When Position('/' In Replace(name, 'posix/', '')) > 0
                   Then SubStr(Replace(name, 'posix/', ''), Position('/' In Replace(name, 'posix/', '')) + 1)
              Else Replace(name, 'posix/', '')
              End as zone, 
              abbrev, utc_offset, is_dst
     From pg_timezone_names
   )
Select   Distinct 
         Case When region In('Etc', zone) Then 'n/a' Else region End as region, 
         zone, abbrev, utc_offset
From     grid
Where    Case When region In('Etc', zone) Then 'n/a' Else region End != 'n/a'
Order By region, zone

